# Convert Pandas DataFrame into JSON

Tags: json, pandas

I have a data frame with over 800,000 rows and 8 columns that looks like this:

```
ID Index Var1   Var2    Var3   Var4  Var5 Var6
1  0     106    114     24     25    1    0
1  1     705    79      19     21    1    0
1  2     661    361     30     37    1    0
1  3     212    332     30     37    1    0
```

I am trying to get this dataframe into a JSON format for a small piece of a larger machine learning project.

I need the json formatted object to look like this:

```
{'source-ref':'s3://sagemaker...jpg',
 'name':{'annotations':[{'ID':1,
 'var1': 106,
 'var2': 114,
 'var3': 24,
 'var4': 25}]}
```

I've tried using the `to_json` function with a combination of the reset_index function on the ID and index.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: So you only need one row of data in the json?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `object-detection` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

800k records will generate a very large JSON object...

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""ID Index Var1   Var2    Var3   Var4  Var5 Var6
1  0     106    114     24     25    1    0
1  1     705    79      19     21    1    0
1  2     661    361     30     37    1    0
1  3     212    332     30     37    1    0"""),sep="\s+")

{'source-ref':'s3://sagemaker...jpg',
 'name':{'annotations':df.to_dict(orient="records")}}
```